# How to populate existing html form with django UpdateView?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to implement a simple UpdateView, but I want to use my own template. Using djangos auto_population is working, but not what I want, because I have lots of fields formatted differently.

```
<form method="post" action="#">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

But I want to use my own form template which looks like this:

**edit_template.html**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{%   url 'update' pk=abc %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
<input name='varX' id="varX" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-class">

<input name='varY' id="varY" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-class">
</form>
```

**views.py**

```
class ModelUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = MyModel
    fields = ['varX','varY']
```

Now I would like that form to be populated with my object data, but the form is empty.

UpdateView is also passing the data twice to the template: One as 'object' and one as 'mymodel'.

I also tried updating

```
get_context_data
```

by adding

```
context.update( model_to_dict(myModelData))
```

But that also does not change anything.

How can I populate my custom form using djangos class-based views?

Comment: Of course it's empty, you've hard-coded empty fields in your HTML. Why don't you use the form fields in that template?

Comment: This is just my template, of course its empty. I don't use the form fields, because I have about 20 fields for my form, which you just cant loop one by one, because they are all different. Also, if I write a normal view function and pass model_to_dict(data) to the context, then it works as intended. It is just not working with class-based views, even if I alter the context. Thats why I am asking this question, because I cannot just use {{ form.as_p }}

Comment: You *can* loop over the fields, or just output them individually. But no, nothing you do in the view could possibly help populate that template because as I said you hard coded the input field in HTML to be empty.

Comment: Actually, you are right. I added value="{{ varX }}" to the input of my fields, which solved my issue.  Thanks again! This should be the preferred answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def get_initial(self):
    initial = super().get_initial()
    initial['my_form_field1'] = self.request.something
    return initial
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at django-widget-tweaks, you first need to check for any non field errors and then loopt through the fields one by one.

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/article/2017/08/19/how-to-render-django-form-manually.html

This article should cover just that